# how to fix Word Splitting

Tags: bash

i have bash-script:

```
for i i in `ldapsearch -xZZLLLD cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -w -b dc=example,dc=com '(&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=cn='$groups',ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com))' dn`
do
echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
dn:
uid=user1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
dn:
uid=user2,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
```

The trouble is that output incorrectly. I read about "word splitting", but don't understand how to fix it. I need get:

```
dn: uid=user1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
dn: uid=user2,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
```

Output command:

```
ldapsearch -xZZLLLD cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -w -b dc=example,dc=com '(&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=cn='$groups',ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com))' dn

dn: uid=user,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com

dn: uid=user1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com

dn: uid=user2,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
```

Comment: Whats the output of `ldapsearch -xZZLLLD cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -w -b dc=example,dc=com '(&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=cn='$groups',ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com))' dn`?

Comment: @heemayl dn: uid=user,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this.

Comment: @heemayl ok, i add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the output from command has space in each line i.e. it outputs `dn: uid=user,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com` (with space between `dn` and `uid=user,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com`), while iterating over the output with `for`, because of word splitting on values of `IFS` (space, tab, newline), you would get two string for each line.

To iterate over each line, use a `while`-`read` construct:

```
ldapsearch -xZZLLLD ... | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done
```